# Trying to list a JSON value using Javascript to my website

Tags: javascript, json

I have a rather large JSON file which contains rating, comments etc for different movies. The syntax is like this:

```
reviews_object={"2396": {"xyz001": {"reg_date": null, "object": 2396, "rating": 3, "mod_date": "2008-11-17", "comment": "", "username": "xyz001"}}, "1107": {"xyz001": {"reg_date": null, "object": 1107, "rating": 4, "mod_date": "2006-11-26", "comment": "", "username": "xyz001"}
```

Javascript code

```
var ratingList = document.querySelector("rating");

function averageRating () {
var reviews = reviews_object;
var reviewList = []; // Array of reviews

for (var i in reviews) {
    reviewList.push(reviews[i])
    console.log(reviewList);
}
```

}

```
function displayRating (reviewList) {
for (var i = 0; i < reviewList.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li")
    li.innerHTML = reviewList[i].rating;
    rating.appendChild(li);

}
```

}

Obviously it doesn't work and I am kinda stuck about what do to next. This JSON file is only for ratings and comments, and I also have one which is about the movie itself (title, length etc). Both the JSON objects has the object ID as you can see in the JSON code i posted. 
What I want to do is to parse through the JSON rating object and list out specifically the rating key and its value to its corresponding object ID from the other JSON file.

Probably a bad explanation of what I want do to, but ask if you wanna know more

Comment: maybe you add the missing parts as well, as the film list and the html part and how review and films match together.

Comment: @JokkeMedKniven where in your code to you cross referenz the lists?  you never define rating and mybe you should consider createing your html in the loop and render it after the loop, this will boost performance when it will work.

Comment: Here are the missing parts:

JSON-object:
movies_object={"1080": {"year": 1957, "otitle": "Ni liv", "youtube trailer id": "", "ntitle": "Ni liv", "mod_date": null, "length": 91, "id": 1080, "keywords": null, "reg_date": null, "description": "J..

Right now HTML is just an <ol> with #rating as ID for testing purposes.
I want the right rating to be listed out to the right movieposter html website

Comment: can a user review more times?

Comment: The rating is already set in the json object, just need to list it out to the correct movie

Comment: @JokkeMedKniven did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

That json represents an object with properties "2396", "1107", not an array.
Your javascript should work, just fix the return from your backend so you get an actual array.

It would need 2 new properties

```
    [{
        "PROPERTY1": "2396",            
        "PROPERTY2": "xyz001",
        "reg_date": null,
        "object": 2396,
        "rating": 3,
        "mod_date": "2008-11-17",
        "comment": "",
        "username": "xyz001"
    },{
        "PROPERTY1": "1107",
        "PROPERTY2": "xyz001",
        "reg_date": null,
        "object": 1107,
        "rating": 4,
        "mod_date": "2006-11-26",
        "comment": "",
        "username": "xyz001"
    }]
```

If you want to have it grouped you should use

```
[{
    "PROPERTY1": "2396",
    "data":[{
        "PROPERTY2": "xyz001",
        "reg_date": null,
        "object": 2396,
        "rating": 3,
        "mod_date": "2008-11-17",
        "comment": "",
        "username": "xyz001"
    },{...}]

}
,{...}]
```

You would have to iterate throught the data property for each node.

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- After pushing the `reviews[i]` into `reviewList` array. The `reviewList` array will be looking like this.

[image]

- Hence, when you will try to access `reviewList[i].rating` in `displayRating` function it will return you `undefined` as `reviewList[i].rating` is not defined as per the `reviewList` structure.

You have to modify your code **:**

```
function displayRating(reviewList) {
    for (var i = 0; i < reviewList.length; i++) {
        console.log(reviewList[i].xyz001.rating);
    }
}
```